# ubuntu login from winwows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login, reboot, secure-boot

I have dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8.1. I restarted the pc with command `shutdown -r now` in Ubuntu Terminal. The PC restarted but now I can only access Windows and can't login to Ubuntu. Previously, the pc gave me options to choose between Ubuntu and Windows but now it doesn't give me options rather it automatically starts windows. Please help me get out of this. I desperately need to login to Ubuntu.

Comment: Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ I believe that'll fix your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Get into BIOS and change the boot order. Its F2 for my asus laptop. You might have to look it up. Change so ubuntu starts first. That should take you to a screen where you can choose the OS.